# Get System.Type instance from within script (ClearScript)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, clearscript

I'm getting an exception when trying to call Enum.Parse from within a script hosted via ClearScript

### Error

```
Error: The non-generic method 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' cannot be used with type arguments
```

```
--- Script error details follow ---
   Error: The non-generic method 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' cannot be used with type arguments
       at translateParameterValue (Script [temp]:11:27) ->          return clr.System.Enum.Parse(app.MyLibrary.MyEnum, value);
```

### Script

```
return clr.System.Enum.Parse(app.MyLibrary.MyEnum, value);
```

I'm pretty sure I registered the `clr` object correctly (this contains `mscorlib`, `System` and `System.Core`)

It seems ClearScript is trying to invoke and is getting confused whether to make the first parameter `app.MyLibrary.MyEnum` a generic parameter or pass it as a `System.Type` parameter.

### Question

What can I do to correctly invoke `System.Enum.Parse` function given this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought. Since ClearScript was treating the first argument like a generic parameter, you just need a function that returns a `System.Type` instance from the type parameter which can be as simple as:

```cs
class Utility
{
    public Type GetType<T>() {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}
```

Then register it to your `ScriptEngine`:

```cs
_engine.AddHostObject("Utility", new Utility());
```

Then use it in your script as:

```
return clr.System.Enum.Parse(Utility.GetType(nepes.DecaTech.CoreData.ProcessStates), value);
```

ClearScript also ships with a utility class `ExtendedHostFunctions` which provides several useful utility functions, including one similar to the above `typeOf(T)`.